# "Let’s start speaking" or "Let’s start to speak"

Tags: meaning, infinitive-vs-gerund

Which one is correct and more common? is there better way?

> - Let’s start speaking English.
> - Let’s start to speak English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the use of the gerund or to-infinitive after the verb *to start*, it seems to be a matter of one's personal preference, at least according to the [BBC Learn English site](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1837_aae/page14.shtml).

At the same time, on some English language forums, you may read that *start to do* can apply to a regular activity and *the gerund* to sudden bursts. I could not find any reliable reference supporting that, though.

As for the use of the gerund vs. to-infinitive after "let's start", I think that a particular context of suggesting something being set in motion might affect your choice.

For example, the verb *to speak* may mean to discuss/convey ideas, in which case the use of the to-infinitive would be quite appropriate:

> Let's start to speak business, politics, etc.

With this in mind, the phrase *"Let's start to speak English"* might be taken sooner as an invite to a discussion about the English language, than as a suggestion of just speaking it, where the gerund should be used:

> Let's start speaking English

For examples of the to-infinitive usage after "Let's start", [see here](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22let%27s+start%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr&ei=qqKqWMiYIoGS6ATZmLcw#lr=lang_en&newwindow=1&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&q=%22let%27s+start+to+%22).