# Watching or to watch. Which one is correct in these two sentences?

Tags: meaning-in-context, infinitive-vs-gerund

Is it ok to say:

> Then, I started watching an episode of...

or should I say

> Then, I started to watch an episode of...

Which one is correct or are both correct? Can you explain me what's the difference between these two sentences? I would really appreciate your help, thank you so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Let’s start speaking" or "Let’s start to speak".](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/119938/let-s-start-speaking-or-let-s-start-to-speak) Also [“Speaking English or to speak English?”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/232079/speaking-english-or-to-speak-english) and possibly others.